# Update sysusers table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, varbinary, sid

I am trying to update the dbo.sysusers table so that the sid matches the dbo.syslogins table but I am getting error:

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type varchar to data type varbinary, table 'CallingCard.dbo.sysusers', column 'sid'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

My syntax for the update is:

```
UPDATE CallingCard.dbo.sysusers 
SET sid = '0xDF5B9900C8FCAE438B0F4177B5'
WHERE uid = 6
```

I don't know how to update a varbinary column. How do i fix this?

Comment: ah, yes thank for that. post it as answer

Comment: You're not supposed to update those system-level catalog views! Those are kept and updated (as needed) by SQL Server itself. If you want to update something - update the **user** in your database - and that change should be reflected in the `sysusers` catalog view after you've made it